# Compiling Ruby and Python interpreters with Clang?

Tags: clang, interpreted-language

I'm just curious; are there any benchmarks about how compiling interpreters for dynamic languages with Clang affects the performance of these languages? Do those interpreters even compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sayspy.blogspot.com/2009/08/compiling-python-using-clang.html

I'd love to see this done in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.9.2-rc2 successfully compiled

http://joneslee85.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/howto-compile-ruby-1-9-2-head-with-clang-svn-head-on-mac-os-x-10-6-3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog entry [Compiling Python using Clang](http://sayspy.blogspot.com/2009/08/compiling-python-using-clang.html).  Sounds like little or no improvement in speed.  Better diagnostics and faster compile though.

Comment: I think you missed the accepted answer to this question which links to the same blog post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390771/compiling-ruby-and-python-interpreters-with-clang/2888722#2888722